# Set read only a .plist file item

Tags: ios, plist

I have a plist file used to store informations as parameters of my application.

It can be configurable by Settings on device and I can set items value programmatically.

Everything working well, but I would like to set items Enable\Disable based on condition.

For example, for some reason I would like to put my item used to store a text information disabled, so the user on device can't edit this parameter on Settings device. Is it possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DefaultValue</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>Key</key>
    <string>USERNAME</string>
    <key>KeyboardType</key>
    <string>Alphabet</string>
    <key>Title</key>
    <string>User</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that kind of flexibility, provide a settings interface within *your* app rather than relying on the Settings app.